# Making Thumbnails, but having trouble with PNG

Tags: php, gd

I'm creating thumbnails using php, and it is working fine for GIF and JPEG, but not for PNG. When I run this script, with a PNG, a thumbnail doesn't save. Can you show me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
public function make_thumbs($img_src)
{
    //Desired thumbnail width 
    $width = 100;
    //Thumbnail name 
    $thumb = 'th_' . $img_src;

    //Ensure the image exists
    if(file_exists($img_src)){

        if (exif_imagetype($img_src) == IMAGETYPE_GIF) 
        {
            //Create image stream 
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($img_src);
        }
        elseif(exif_imagetype($img_src) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG)
        {
            //Create image stream 
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_src);
        }
        elseif(exif_imagetype($img_src) == IMAGETYPE_PNG)
        {
            //Create image stream 
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($img_src);
        }


        //Gather and store the width and height
        list($image_width, $image_height) = getimagesize($img_src);

        //Calculate new height while maintaining aspect ratio 
        $height = (($width / $image_width) * $image_height);

        //Resample/resize the image 
        $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $image_width, $image_height);

        //Attempt to save the new thumbnail 
        if(is_writeable(dirname($thumb)))
        {
            if (exif_imagetype($img_src) == IMAGETYPE_GIF) 
            {
                imagegif($tmp_img, $thumb, 100);
            }
            elseif(exif_imagetype($img_src) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG)
            {
                imagejpeg($tmp_img, $thumb, 100);
            }
            elseif(exif_imagetype($img_src) == IMAGETYPE_PNG)
            {
                imagepng($tmp_img, $thumb, 100);
            }
            }

            //clear memory 
            imagedestroy($tmp_img);
            imagedestroy($image);
        }
        }
```

Comment: Try throwing a deliberate warning (e.g. print an undefined var), and a deliberate error (e.g. division by zero), to ensure that your on-screen error reporting is turned on. Also check your logs for any errors. Lastly, do you get anything for `$image_width` and `$image_height` when the PNG section is run?

Comment: please check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.gd-info.php and find out if PNG is supported. post back your findings and we can proceed from there

Comment: This is what came back: array(12) { ["GD Version"]=> string(27) "bundled (2.0.34 compatible)" ["FreeType Support"]=> bool(true) ["FreeType Linkage"]=> string(13) "with freetype" ["T1Lib Support"]=> bool(false) ["GIF Read Support"]=> bool(true) ["GIF Create Support"]=> bool(true) ["JPEG Support"]=> bool(true) ["PNG Support"]=> bool(true) ["WBMP Support"]=> bool(true) ["XPM Support"]=> bool(false) ["XBM Support"]=> bool(true) ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=> bool(false) }

Comment: Worked it out. I was setting the PNG quality to 100. It can only be a value between 0 and 9. I tried to add an answer, but my reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: @user1660638 I have been looking everywhere to solve this issue. Thanks for sharing